# DropDown Box selection shows text boxes in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, show-hide

```html
<div class="row500">
   <span class="cell200">
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCollision" runat="server" Height="28px" Width="354px" Style="font-size: 18px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCollision_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
     
<asp:ListItem Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Cars</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">People</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
 </span>
</div>

<br/>
 <div class="row500"  id="fixedObject" runat="server">
    <span class="cell200">
    <asp:Label ID="lblFixed" runat="server" Text="Car Label:"> </asp:Label>
            </span>
            <br />
       
    <span class="cell200">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server">     </asp:TextBox>    
   </span>
   </div>
```

I am currently working on a asp.net C# webpage that contains a drop down list has roughly 5 list items with values from 0-4. Everytime a user selects one of the items I want the number to correspond to the number of text boxes that will appear. So, if a user selects "2" from the drop down list, I need to show/hide divs that contain the textboxes and make 2 text boxes appear..Any help on this would be great!!!!

My attempt: 
Code under drop down list

```
protected void ddlCollision_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlCollision.SelectedValue == "1")
        fixedObject.Visible = true;
    else
        fixedObject.Visible = false;
}
```

fixed object is the id of the div that contains the textbox

Comment: You should post your attempt at this!

Comment: @adam i just edited it!

Comment: Did you set `AutoPostBack="true"` for your DropDownList?

Comment: yes i did @ConnorsFan

Comment: Please show us the relevant markup (DropDownList, divs).

Comment: mark up is added! @ConnorsFan

Answer (score 0):

You can even add textboxes dynamically based on the integer count that is selected from your dropdownlist. Then for that `count` number of times, it will run and add that many textboxes.

```
  protected void ddlOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int loopcnt = 1; loopcnt <= Convert.ToInt32(ddlOptions.SelectedValue.Trim()); loopcnt++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "tb" + loopcnt;
        ctrlPlaceholder.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  Question:
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <br />
  <br />Number of Options:
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOptions" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlOptions_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
  <br />
  <br />Options:
  <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ctrlPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
```

Comment: i want the textboxes to line up vertically this does it horizontally! how can i do this? @Maheswari

Comment: Add the textboxes to dynamic table and finally add table to place holder.Here is the code

Answer (score 0):

protected void ddlOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        Int32 pickedValue = Int32.Parse(ddlOptions.SelectedValue);

            Table table = new Table();


            for (int i = 1; i <= pickedValue; i++)
            {

                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

                TextBox txt_splzn = new TextBox();

                txt_splzn.ID = "txtB" + i.ToString();
                txt_splzn.Text = "Text Number " + i.ToString();

                cell.Controls.Add(txt_splzn);

                row.Cells.Add(cell);
                table.Rows.Add(row);
                ctrlPlaceholder.Controls.Add(table);
            }
        }

}
```